# creating user defined encoding conversions in postgres

Tags: postgresql, encoding, type-conversion, user-defined-functions

I'm attempting to create a custom encoding conversion function in PostgreSQL using the `CREATE CONVERSION` statement. However, I'm struggling to find appropriate resources or examples to guide me in writing the conversion function.

Could someone provide guidance on how to write this function using the syntax specified in the official documentation?
([https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createconversion.html#:~:text=destination%20encoding%20name.-,function_name,-The%20function%20used](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createconversion.html#:%7E:text=destination%20encoding%20name.-,function_name,-The%20function%20used)).

Comment: Why do you want this? This sounds like an attempt to cover up a bug or bad design. Creating a custom conversion won't fix them. If you store Unicode text you don't have to worry about conversions. String in Python, Java, Javascript, C# (.NET in general) are Unicode. It would take a pretty serious application bug to treat strings as ASCII in any of these languages. If you *don't* use Unicode in PostgreSQL, you'll  have to use the exact same encoding in the column collation and application. Not doing so is a bug that can easily *lose* data, not just mangle it

Comment: As for the question itself, `conv_func` refers to the *C* function that converts one encoding to another. If you search for this, you can find the [existing conversion functions in Github](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/utils/mb/conversion_procs/utf8_and_iso8859_1/utf8_and_iso8859_1.c). That's not something you can do if you don't already understand about encoding conversions or how they're done in C or C++